# Azure App Service: Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have been trying to switch the server side of my app from Azure Mobile Service to Azure App Service for the better flexibility in pay scale. I finally got it to run on a local debugger, but when i deploy to the server i get an error page. I went into the diagnostic in the portal and i get this error. any ideas are appreciated.

```
    Exception information:
    Exception type: FileLoadException
    Exception message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server,
    Version=0.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
    or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match
    the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) at
    System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken,
    IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs,
    Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type) at
    System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken,
    RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
    at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments,
    Type[] genericMethodArguments) at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord
    (CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly,
    RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType,
    Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes,
    RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters,
    Boolean& isVarArg) at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(
    RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount,
    RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes,
    Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent) at
    System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeAssembly assembly,
    RuntimeType caType) at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetCustomAttributes
    (Boolean inherit) at Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.SearchForStartupAttribute
    (String friendlyName, IList`1 errors, Boolean& conflict) at
    Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.GetDefaultConfiguration(String friendlyName, IList`1 errors)
    at Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.LoadImplementation(String startupName, IList`1 errorDetails)
    at Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.Load(String startupName, IList`1 errorDetails)
    at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinBuilder.GetAppStartup() at
    Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.InitializeBlueprint()
    at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore[T]
    (T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory) at 
    Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context) at
    System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS
    (IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) at
    System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
    MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) at
    System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance
    (IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) at 
    System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the version of the package you are referencing via NuGet and update to the last version, if possible. The last published version of the Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Service is 1.0.0.0.

I think one of your dependencies is trying to load the 0.1.0.0 dll version.

If updating the NuGet packages does not change anything, you can add a binding redirect to redirect all calls to the 0.1.0.0 to version referenced in your project (see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/eftw1fys(v=vs.110).aspx).

Hope this helps,

Julien